# After an update of ESET smart security, error message pops up on Windows 7

Tags: anti-virus, updates, windows-7

The ESET smart security update has been successfully installed and started to work for a while, but the Windows 7 action center places a red cross in the right area hand tray on the icon and when I open the action center, I get this message to the effect that;

> No Anti-virus program can be found on my Computer

**Why would this happen?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a support question regarding the interaction between two commercial closed-source products (ESET and Windows). Please contact the support of the vendors of these products for help instead.

Comment: You can choose to ignore it, reinstall it or contact the AV tech support.
It is a known issue in some windows version, which normally should not affect antivirus functionality.